# Oracle SQL; how to remove the duplicates of a "default" record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called T_COUNTRIES where the names in different languages for all countries are stored.

The Default Country name for a given Country Code is identified by the SYSCOUNTRY "ALL" and SYSLANG "eng" (see row in violet).

The application will automatically revert to the Default Country name if no translation for a certain language is found.

So I would like to remove all records (those in red) that have the same COUNTRYCODE and COUNTRYNAME as the Default (the one in violet) since they are duplicates.

Those in green should stay since the COUNTRYNAME translation for a certain COUNTRYCODE differs from the Default.

I was thinking about this query, but it does not take into account COUNTRYCODE at all:

```
SELECT * FROM T_COUNTRIES WHERE SYSCOUNTRY <> 'ALL' AND COUNTRYNAME IN 
(SELECT COUNTRYNAME FROM T_COUNTRIES WHERE SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select the green rows using CONCAT:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_countries
WHERE syscountry <> 'ALL'
AND concat(countrycode, countryname) NOT IN 
(SELECT concat(countrycode, countryname) 
FROM t_countries
WHERE syscountry = 'ALL')
```

Alternatively, here is how to identify the red rows using a join:

```
SELECT t_countries.*
FROM t_countries
INNER JOIN
(SELECT countrycode, countryname
 FROM t_countries
 WHERE syscountry = 'ALL') sub
 ON t_countries.countrycode = sub.countrycode
 AND t_countries.countryname = sub.countryname
 AND syscountry <> 'ALL'
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df695/7

Comment: Great! Glad to help :)

Comment: For anybody interested this is the full query for the deletion of the duplicate records:                                                                             `DELETE t_countries WHERE rowid IN
(SELECT t_countries.rowid FROM t_countries
INNER JOIN
(SELECT countrycode, countryname FROM t_countries
 WHERE syscountry = 'ALL') global
 ON t_countries.countrycode = global.countrycode
 AND t_countries.countryname = global.countryname
 AND t_countries.syscountry <> 'ALL');`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to be like

```
SELECT * FROM 
T_COUNTRIES 
WHERE COUNTRYNAME <> 
(SELECT COUNTRYNAME FROM T_COUNTRIES WHERE SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL')
```

Per your comment, change the query to be

```
SELECT * FROM 
T_COUNTRIES 
WHERE COUNTRYNAME = 
(SELECT COUNTRYNAME FROM T_COUNTRIES WHERE SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL')
```

See the [Your Modified Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c905e/8)

Comment: This would remove all records with a different COUNTRYNAME, also the ones in green.

Comment: Yes I have tested it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c905e/1/0
It selects (delete) the green rows instead of the red ones.

Comment: @Forna, your post is bit confusing. Anyways see edit in answer if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rows with the different COUNTRYNAME compared to SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL' row for that COUNTRYCODE . Assuming there's no more then 1 row exists with SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL' for any COUNTRYCODE. ( "Correct" rows).

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
T_COUNTRIES t
WHERE SYSCOUNTRY <> 'ALL' 
   AND COUNTRYNAME <> (SELECT t2.COUNTRYNAME 
         FROM T_COUNTRIES t2 
         WHERE t2.SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL' AND t2.COUNTRYCODE = t.COUNTRYCODE)
```

Rows to be deleted

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
T_COUNTRIES t
WHERE SYSCOUNTRY <> 'ALL' 
   AND COUNTRYNAME = (SELECT t2.COUNTRYNAME 
         FROM T_COUNTRIES t2 
         WHERE t2.SYSCOUNTRY = 'ALL' AND t2.COUNTRYCODE = t.COUNTRYCODE)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tested and it and it does not seem to work, it would remove all the records with a different COUNTRYNAME.

Comment: This was supposed to select "correct" rows. See updated answer